# Authentication Flow with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter. I am trying to set up an authentication flow. if the user is not logged in, I plan to build a MaterialApp with certain routes (eg Facebook Auth, Google Auth and Email Auth). If the user is logged in, they ll see another MaterialApp with routes such as HomePage, ListPage, CreatePage etc.

I tried but below codes fail. Anyone with experience can advise? thanks in advance

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

import './pages/email.dart';
import './pages/auth.dart';
import './pages/home.dart';
import './pages/list.dart';
import './pages/create.dart';
import './scoped-models/main.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final MainModel _model = MainModel();
  bool _isAuthenticated = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _model.autoAuthenticate();
    _model.userSubject.listen((bool isAuthenticated) {
      setState(() {
        _isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(_isAuthenticated);
    return ScopedModel<MainModel>(
      model: _model,
      child: !_isAuthenticated == true
          ? MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData(
                  primaryColor: Colors.lime, buttonColor: Colors.teal),
              routes: {
                '/': (BuildContext context) => AuthPage(),
                '/email': (BuildContext context) => EmailPage(),
              },
            )
          : MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData(
                  primaryColor: Colors.lime, buttonColor: Colors.teal),
              routes: {
                '/': (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
                '/list': (BuildContext context) => ListPage(),
                '/create': (BuildContext context) => CreatePage()
              },
            ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Instead of having a different materialapp, use `onGenerateRoute`

Comment: Hi Remi, thanks. it works and the code is cleaner! if i add in an email login page on top of the general auth page which displays 3 buttons (google, facebook and email login), then it breaks. google and facebook will navigate from the auth page, email login will go to another screen which allows user to choose sign up or sign in and navigate it from there

Comment: @RémiRousselet, please post as an answer so others may benefit.